# Can't find Microsoft Internet controls library in available references for Excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape data from the web using vba and I need to add Microsoft Internet controls library to my references but have limitied options available. Do I have the wrong version of excel? 
You can see by the scroll bar in the screen shot that I have very few available references to choose from. Any ideas to why?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You're on a Mac, so many of the options which are available on Windows will not be on your system.  VBA in Mac Office is a different experience from VBA on Windows

Comment: And not generally a pleasant one.